# How to make body scrollLeft on ScrollDown and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have put together a little code that I had hoped would allow the html to scroll to the left whenever a user scrolls down and scroll right when the user scrolls up

I've put together an example of my code here [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6bzrj7wy/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
            $('html, body').scrollRight(1);
        }
        else {
            $('html, body').scrollLeft(1);
        }
    });
});
```

I need to prevent the user from scrolling vertically and want the vertical scrolls to cause horizontal scrolling instead.

Comment: jQuery only provides a `scrollLeft()` method. Add the `wheelDelta` to the current `scrollLeft` value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you miss te parenthesis at the end of the `preventDefault()` call. That's why the vertical scrollbar still works.

Second, there is no such jQuery method as `scrollRight()`. You should use the `scrollLeft()` method for both direction.

See your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bzrj7wy/4/)!

Comment: your example is not working for me. Also I updated the post with the parenthesis

Comment: It had an unsaved draft, but it should work now. Try it again, please!

Answer (score 0):

The scrollRight method is not defined by jQuery so you have to use scrollLeft.

When you call scrollLeft without any arguments you get the current scroll position (starting from the left edge). When you call scrollLeft(value) you set the current scroll position to value (ref. https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/).

Following snippet works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var body = $('body');
  $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    body.scrollLeft(body.scrollLeft() - e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
  });
});
```

```css
section {
  width: 500vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  /*unimportant */
  background: rgba(76,76,76,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(76,76,76,1)), color-stop(12%, rgba(89,89,89,1)), color-stop(25%, rgba(102,102,102,1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(71,71,71,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(44,44,44,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(76%, rgba(43,43,43,1)), color-stop(91%, rgba(28,28,28,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19,19,19,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(76,76,76,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(19,19,19,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section></section>
```

Comment: your example works but in my code it scrolls right one time and cannot scroll right anymore, even though there is much farther it is able to scroll

Comment: That's because the scrollLeft(value) function sets the scroll position to value. It does not increment the scroll position by value. So on every mousewheel event you are setting the scroll position to 1. That's why it only changes once.

Comment: I copied your code exactly though, how do I make it work?

Comment: It should work like it does in the code snippet above. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: No problem. I made a small change just now to reverse the scrolling direction.